# How can I redirect .NET core 3.1 Open ID Connect to public url after successful auth?

Tags: c#, .net-core, openid-connect

I have a .NET Core 3.1 Blazor app which uses AddOpenIdConnect (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.openidconnectextensions.addopenidconnect?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

All works well locally when I setup the options for the ID Server authority etc.

The problem is when in the development environment the app runs on mysite.local and is publicly available on mysite.public so when the auth happens via ID Server the redirect is to https://mysite.local/signin-oidc not https://mysite.public/signin-oidc

No matter what I do this will not redirect back to the public url.  I've tried

```cs
services.AddOpenIdConnect("oicd", options => {
   ...
   options.CallbackPath = "https://mysite.public/signin-oidc"; // exception - path must start with '/'
   options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc"; // redirects to https://mysite.local/signin-oidc
   ...
})
```

and also set the redirecturi in the login page:

```cs
public class LoginModel: PageModel
{
   public async Task OnGet(string redirectUri)
   {
      await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("oidc",
         new AuthenticationProperties 
         {
            RedirectUri = redirectUri
         })
   }
}
```

with

```html
<a href="login?redirectUri=https://mysite.public/original-page">Log in</a>
```

Any ideas gratefully received, is there some way to set the base uri maybe?

Comment: A good starting point is to create separate Client entry  in IdentityServer for development and production.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to do anything about ID Server.  I had wanted them to implement auto discovery etc. but it was a no.  Internal politics.

Comment: I mean a client definition inside IdentityServer (the client id/password) , so you use different redirect urls for develpment and production?

Comment: It should go to the callbackPath in the original url though shouldn't it?  So I'm getting the AWS app name I think not the public url

Comment: the redirect URL must be the public URL that the browser sees, as the redirect is carried out by the browser.